# Model Attributes on Find

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model and would like to get two attributes after find.

for e.g.

```
 User.find(@id).select { |u| u.first_name + ' ' + u.last_name}
```

but it gives error. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like :

```
@user = User.find(@id)
"#{@user.first_name} #{@user.last_name}"
```

(The second line returns what you want but I definitely advice you to create a method in the model)

Comment: I am sorry.. Forgot to mention, the code is in .erb
<%= User.find(@id).select { |u| u.first_name + ' ' + u.last_name} %>

Comment: So the first line should be in the controller and the second needs to be wrapped inside `<%= %>`